# mysql question - way to update case for field?

Tags: mysql, text, field

I have some entries in a field that look like this:  NEvada city  or nevada City... Is there a way to update the database so that entries have initial caps: Nevada City?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
UPDATE `table` SET
`field` = CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(`field`, 1)), LOWER(SUBSTRING(`field`, 2)))
```

But still you will need to modify it to allow a capital Letter for the next word like `City`...

Source [here](http://www.strictlyphp.com/blog/2008/08/15/uppercase-first-letter-of-a-string-with-mysql/)

***UPDATE:***
Found [this](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,265978,266040#msg-266040) example at MySQL's forum, it is exactly what you need:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS proper;
SET GLOBAL  log_bin_trust_function_creators=TRUE;
DELIMITER |
CREATE FUNCTION proper( str VARCHAR(128) )
RETURNS VARCHAR(128)
BEGIN
  DECLARE c CHAR(1);
  DECLARE s VARCHAR(128);
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE bool INT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE punct CHAR(17) DEFAULT ' ()[]{},.-_!@;:?/';
  SET s = LCASE( str );
  WHILE i < LENGTH( str ) DO 
    BEGIN
      SET c = SUBSTRING( s, i, 1 );
      IF LOCATE( c, punct ) > 0 THEN
        SET bool = 1;
      ELSEIF bool=1 THEN 
        BEGIN
          IF c >= 'a' AND c <= 'z' THEN 
            BEGIN
              SET s = CONCAT(LEFT(s,i-1),UCASE(c),SUBSTRING(s,i+1));
              SET bool = 0;
            END;
          ELSEIF c >= '0' AND c <= '9' THEN
            SET bool = 0;
          END IF;
        END;
      END IF;
      SET i = i+1;
    END;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN s;
END;
|
DELIMITER ;
```